# Saying "Call Joe Bloggs" doesn't work on Huawei Y330

Tags: calls, google-now, huawei

I bought my grandad a cheap Android phone - a Huawei Ascend Y330 - for Christmas. He likes Google Now a lot, but for some reason the command `Call <somebody in his phone book>` isn't working.

It's saying (in a robotic voice, not the usual one) `Say the name of the contact you want to call, or say cancel`. It isn't coming up with any contact suggestions either, and it isn't working for any contacts, from simple `home` to slightly more complicated names.

Initially it came up with a permission request to access his contacts, which I approved.

Saying `Call ACME Inc` *does* work though, when it needs to search online for the number.

It's running Android 4.2 Jellybean and there are no updates available.

Any ideas?

Comment: I suppose I could flash it? Any lightweight ROMs you can suggest or any considerations for this model phone with rooting it?

Comment: Check your Google Now settings, go into "Phone Search" and check whether "Contacts" is ticked. There's a possibility that this isn't ticked for unknown reason.

Comment: did it use to work perfectly when you bought?

Comment: @Apurva It's only just been bought, it's new.

Comment: @AndrewT. Thanks for the idea, please see my comment on Cross Cudi's answer.

Comment: I don't know whether it will work but you should try clearing data of Google Now. Go to phone settings -> apps -> installed -> google now -> clear data. It will initialize your app. The path I have suggested might not be true because I have not use new android OS. But I know you can clear app data and initialize by going in settings -> installed app.

Comment: Hi @Apurva - there is no Google Now listed in the Installed Apps (I first clicked All) :(

Comment: @Apurva I found Google Search and Voice Search and cleared the app data and caches for both. It started the setup wizard for Now again, but it still isn't working.

Comment: Saying "Text Billy" doesn't work either - same problem - "say the name of the contact you want to text or say cancel"

Comment: sorry now I can't help you I haven't used any latest android phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at ROMs and trying to choose one, and Googling for this problem, I found many forum threads of people with similar problems.

The solution I ended up using was to install an alternative speech recognition app - [utter!](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.brandall.nutter&hl=en)

It's working great and even has more features than Google Now does :)

Answer (score 0):

First, check the settings under Google Now. Open "Phone Search" and check if "Contacts" is ticked. If it is not, then tick it and it should work. If it is, head to Settings and Application Manager. Get to Google App and uninstall updates. Get back to the Play Store and reinstall all updates. It should work. If all else fails and he hasn't much data on the phone, back up and format it. Good luck and thank you for the bounty.

Comment: Thanks for the idea; going into Google Now's Settings prompted me to sign an account. Created a Google account, and then a couple of Google Now-related updates downloaded. It's still not working though. Same symptoms as before. I don't think restoring to factory would help. Think I'd need another ROM. It currently runs Emotion UI.